# OnboardSDK: mission management and HomePoint initialization

Tags: dji-sdk

I am having Matrice 210 and use OSDK for uploading mission. But the OSDK will not allow uploading if the HomePoint of  the aircraft was not initialized.

I got error "WAYPOINT_MISSION_POINTS_TOO_FAR" if turning on the drone only, and I have to turn on RC and connect DJI GO application for the HomePoint being created.

If I understand correctly, the mission manager only accept mission when the drone has strong GPS signal, but the document do not say anything about the HomePoint initializing. 
I try to find in the SDK a function to tell the drone get it current GPS as HomePoint, but there is no such thing available in the code. Do I miss something?

**Update:**
Here is how I setup the mission manager:

```
void setWaypointInitDefaults(WayPointInitSettings* fdata)
{
   fdata->maxVelocity = 10;
   fdata->idleVelocity = 5;
   fdata->finishAction = 0;
   fdata->executiveTimes = 1;
   fdata->yawMode = 0;
   fdata->traceMode = 0;
   fdata->RCLostAction = 1;
   fdata->gimbalPitch = 0;
   fdata->latitude = 0;
   fdata->longitude = 0;
   fdata->altitude = 0;
}
...
bool InitWaypointMission(Vehicle* vehicle, int numberWaypoints, double maxSpeed, double turnSpeed, bool usePointsHeading)
{
   WayPointInitSettings fdata;
   setWaypointInitDefaults(&fdata);
   fdata.indexNumber = numberWaypoints;
   fdata.maxVelocity = maxSpeed;
   fdata.idleVelocity = turnSpeed;
   if ( usePointsHeading )
      fdata.yawMode = 3;

   ACK::ErrorCode initAck = vehicle->missionManager->init(DJI_MISSION_TYPE::WAYPOINT, responseTimeout, &fdata);
   if (ACK::getError(initAck))
   {
        ACK::getErrorCodeMessage(initAck, __func__);
        return false;
   }
   vehicle->missionManager->printInfo();
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On DJI drones, the Homepoint is automatically acquired when the drone has visibility of enough GPS satellites. A method that can tell the drone to get its' current position as homepoint will not be useful - if the drone can indeed get a good fix on its' current location in GPS co-ordinates, it has already set it as a homepoint, or will do so in the next few seconds.

There may be many reasons why you are getting the WAYPOINT_MISSION_POINTS_TOO_FAR error, but you will need to provide more context to help us narrow it down. Some things that are useful to report:

- After powering on the drone, how long are you letting it sit in clear
  skies before trying to upload the mission?
- When you initialize your waypoint mission through the MissionManager, have you made sure to set the `RCLostAction` to `Keep Going`?
- Is the behavior reproducible in simulation?

Comment: Does the drone require RC connection to have better GPS fix? because I power the drone only, and turn off RC. Let it there more than 5 mins but mission manager does not allow me upload mission. But when RC and DJI GO app turned on, and after the announcement: "The homepoint has ben updated..." I can upload mission.

Comment: And I can reproduce in simulation when the RC and DJI GO turned off.